# TestFixtureSetUp failed occasionally while running through cc.net

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I am running nightly builds using cc.net 1.4.2. I am also using nunit2.4.8. If I force the build manually it works fine but most of my nightly schduled builds fails saying testfixture setup failed. Is this some bug in nunit2.4.8 or something othert thing as I cant find out the reason

Comment: I just started getting this issue this morning with CC.NET and NUnit 2.4.6. My unit tests run fine on my dev machine, but now on the CC.NET server all my tests say "TestFixtureSetUp failed in Setup".

Comment: Turns out my test database was out of date so calls to the DB were failing in my setup. Maybe you changed something recently or have you always had the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Is it the same cc.net project being forced that is scheduled to run nightly?  If not, there may be a difference in how they are configured.  If they are the same, I would suggest adding some logging to the test fixture setup code to see if you can track down the problem.  Perhaps there is a nightly task running on the server (backup or virus scan perhaps) that is causing the issue. Another possibility is a task running on another server (taking a database offline for example.) I don't believe this is a bug in NUnit.